# How can I pass extra details from simpleForm elements to my controller in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, model-associations

I'm using SimpleForm in Rails and I have 2 fields presented to the user to choose a location (a rich association) from a pre-filtered set of Locations. Each choice needs to be saved in the join table along with the type of location that it is.

How can I create a form that will send back info to my controller that can tell me what 'type' of location is being selected.

```
_new_flow_form.html

      <%= simple_form_for @new_flow,:url => {:action => "company_create_flow", :controller => 'flows'}, :html => { :class => 'form-horizontal', :multipart => true } do |f| %>

            <%= f.label 'Workflow Title', :class => 'control-label' %>
            <%= f.text_field :title, :class => 'form-control' %>

            <%= f.association :locations, collection: Location.where(:company_id => @company.id, :source => 'TRUE'), :label => 'Source Location' %>
            <%= f.association :locations, collection: Location.where(:company_id => @company.id, :destination => 'TRUE'), :label => 'Destinations'%>

            <%= f.submit nil, :class => 'btn btn-primary' %>
      <% end %>
```

For reference, my models look like this:

location.rb

```
  class Flow < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :flow_locations
    has_many :locations, :through => :flow_locations
  end
```

flow.rb

```
  class Location < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :flow_locations
    has_many :flows, :through => :flow_locations
  end
```

flow_location.rb

```
  class FlowLocation < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :flow
    belongs_to :location

    serialize :source
    serialize :destination
  end
```

The current result that I get when the form is submitted is this:

```
{
"utf8": "✓",
"authenticity_token": "Z3f4lByIebmvz4wgFGQGPP7xoVeLIFgSE0MSak9KfZxP3yoH7SFBjH5upD+mx+pRZ61bXqwl+e2o3qEX3dfYAw==",
"flow": {
    "title": "testMe",
    "company_id": "1",
    "service_ids": [
        "",
        "2"
    ],
    "location_ids": [
        "",
        "3",
        "",
        "1"
    ]
},
"commit": "Create Flow"
}
```

And the major problem here is that, I have no way of deciphering from this which of those location_ids are for 'Sources' vs which ones are for 'Destinations'

Can anyone help me understand what I might be able to do different here to get back something better from the view that can tell me specifically which location_id is for which?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just change the `name` attribute of the HTML elements:

```
<%= f.association :locations, collection: Location.where(:company_id => @company.id, :source => 'TRUE'), :label => 'Source Location' name: "source_ids" %>
<%= f.association :locations, collection: Location.where(:company_id => @company.id, :destination => 'TRUE'), :label => 'Destinations' name: "destination_ids"%>
```

But this will push the attribute out of the `flow` object

```
{
"utf8": "✓",
"authenticity_token": "Z3f4lByIebmvz4wgFGQGPP7xoVeLIFgSE0MSak9KfZxP3yoH7SFBjH5upD+mx+pRZ61bXqwl+e2o3qEX3dfYAw==",
"flow": {
    "title": "testMe",
    "company_id": "1",
    "service_ids": [
        "",
        "2"
    ]    },
"commit": "Create Flow",
"source_ids":[
    "1"
 ],
"destination_ids":[
    "3"
 ]
}
```

**OR**

In Rails 4 you can use scoped association in your `Flow` model:

```
class Flow < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :flow_locations
  has_many :destinations, -> { destinations: true }, :class_name => 'Location', :through => :flow_locations
  has_many :sources, -> { source: true }, :class_name => 'Location', :through => :flow_locations
  has_many :destinations, 
end
```

and update your view `_new_flow_form.html` accordingly:

```
<%= f.association :sources, collection: Location.where(:company_id => @company.id, :source => 'TRUE'), :label => 'Source Location' %>
<%= f.association :destinations, collection: Location.where(:company_id => @company.id, :destination => 'TRUE'), :label => 'Destinations'%>
```